# Deleting everything in a single column after a certain pattern

Tags: shell, awk, replace, sed

I have following lines

```
ABC-Dup2  XUAS  BSNMM
CVD  nbvn  nbmsb
SVDB-Dup4  NBV  KJHA
TTS-Dup7  MNMN  NBA
```

I want to remove -Dup from the FIRST COLUMN ONLY and retain rest of the columns such that I have

```
ABC  XUAS  BSNMM
CVD  nbvn  nbmsb
SVDB  NBV  KJHA
TTS  MNMN  NBA
```

I am trying sed 's/-Dup.*//1' but it's removing the rest of the columns from that row too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pattern is -Dup followed by a number then you could try something like

`sed 's/-Dup[0-9]*//1'`

Comment: Try that if the 2nd line of input was `CVD  nbvn-Dup7  nbmsb`. The `1` at the end is for the first occurrence of the regexp, it's not a field number.

Comment: I know that, the test sample from the OP doesn't mention the -Dup pattern could be anywhere other than the first column though

Comment: No but he does say `FIRST COLUMN ONLY` in nice, big capital letters so IMHO that is a pretty strong hint. The `1` is redundant, btw, that's the default behavior.

Answer (score 3):

If you changed the `.*` to `[^[:blank:]]*` you would no longer have that problem but you'd still have the problem of sed removing `-Dup` from **anywhere** on the line, not just the first column. Just use awk:

```
awk '{sub(/-Dup.*/,"",$1)}1' file
```

Notice how that **only** operates on the first column (field):

```
$ cat file
ABC-Dup2  XUAS  BSNMM
CVD  nbvn-Dup7  nbmsb
SVDB-Dup4  NBV  KJHA
TTS-Dup7  MNMN  NBA

$ awk '{sub(/-Dup.*/,"",$1)}1' file
ABC XUAS BSNMM
CVD  nbvn-Dup7  nbmsb
SVDB NBV KJHA
TTS MNMN NBA
```

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` solution needs to incorporate the field delimiter to define the target to be first column only.  GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's/^(\S*)-Dup\S*/\1/' file

ABC  XUAS  BSNMM
CVD  nbvn  nbmsb
SVDB  NBV  KJHA
TTS  MNMN  NBA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\(^[^ ]*\)-Dup[0-9]*/\1/'
```